# Octave 4.0 `imwrite` png: `BitDepth` 4?

Tags: image, octave

Matlab's `imwrite` allows me to specify paired arguments `'BitDepth',4` when writing a 2D `uint16` array to a file '*.png'.  My Octave's `imwrite` doesn't accept the paired arguments `'BitDepth',4`.  I can exercise some limited control of bit depth, however, if I scale the data for `uint8` and save it to a 2D `uint8` array; the '*.png' from `imwrite` is then just over half the size the file for a `uint16` array.  I got the idea to do this by looking at `imread`, for which the bit depth of the source image file determines the `uint` type of the destination variable.  Assuming that the `uint` type of the source 2D image array similarly determines the bit depth of the `imwrite` destination file, `uint8` yields a bit depth of 8.  I found, however, that a bit depth of 2 is often enough for 100 dpi grayscale scans of hand notes.  **Is there an easy way to have such arbitrary bit depth control for `imwrite`?**

**Aside:** Regarding the reference to `uint16` above, I didn't just make that up.  It's the default from a conversion from colour RGB.  From a web search, I found a conversion method for my old Octave 4.0 (no `rgb2gray`):

```
im=imread('rgb.jpeg');
[imInd,Ind]=rgb2ind(im);
imGray16=ind2gray(imInd,Ind); imwrite(imGray16,'gray16b.png');
imGray8=uint8(imGray16/256); imwrite(imGray8,'gray8b.png');
```

I am using the Octave installation that is part of Cygwin.  However, the laptop I use has limited user rights, and upgrading Octave requires phenomenal amounts of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your question, you can't set `BitDepth` when calling `imwrite`.  The function will write an image with the data type of the variable (provided that the image file type supports it).

If you really need arbitrary bit depth control when writing the file, you would need to interact with libpng directly, that is, write your own oct function.

However, there's a few things about your comments:

1. the issue of converting from uint16 -> uint8 and getting more than half the size, I'm guessing is because the image is compressed.
2. `rgb2ind` does nor convert to `uint16` by default.  It will convert to `uint8` or `uint16` depending on the number of unique colours in your image.
3. the function `rgb2gray` is part of the image package.  Load that package if you want that function.

Comment: Thaks for that, carandraug.  I'm new to packages (and relatively new to Octave) but googled around for the installation.  I get the error "unable to find the mkoctfile command, Octave installation is incomplete". I didn't build Octave, it was from an old Cygwin install.  `which mkoctfile` gives the full path to mkoctfile.m, which I can pipe through `less`.  At some point (possibly way in the future), I will have to update my Cygwin to see if the problem is still there.

Comment: @user36800 is there a reason to not scipt cygwin and use the MXE installer instead? I think it's also possible to install it without administrator rights and there is AFAIK even a portable version which you can install on an external medium

Comment: I had to move heaven and earth just to get cygwin.  In my shop, getting approval install anything is a big deal.  At this point, it'd be easier to approve cygwin update CDs than to bring attention to something new.  But that's "OK" (to the extent that it can be OK) since I'm deeply cozy with the linux environment and all its little conveniences.